# Type Function Aliases in Idris

Tags: idris

Is it possible to define a short alias of a type function in Idris?

While the following code type-checks, I'd like to have a shorter definition for **AugentRow**.

```
import Data.Vect

ColumnCount : Type
ColumnCount = Nat

Cell : Type
Cell = Type

Row : ColumnCount -> Cell -> Type
Row   columnCount    cell =  Vect columnCount cell

AugentRow : ColumnCount -> Cell -> Type
AugentRow   columnCount    cell =  Row columnCount cell
```

Some definition without unnessesory repetition like this one:

```
AugentRow = Row
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest form I've found so far:

```
AugentRow : ColumnCount -> Cell -> Type
AugentRow = Row
```

Comment: this is the shortest I've come across, though I've generally found it difficult working in code bases where there are multiple names for the exact same type